# How to speed-up boot by disabling few dev-loox.device?

Tags: boot, 18.10, df, loop-device

When I checked my system's boot logs, I noticed that each of the `dev-loopx.device` takes a good 3-5 seconds to boot, and I have a total 20 such loopx devices lines up during my boot, which ultimately slows down my boot.

To get further details on these loopx devices, I ran the following command

$ df -a -h -T

And the most important part of the output was:

[image]

Why are some applications (or part of them) is being loaded during boot, which I don't even use in every session?

For example, the **gaome-calculator** application, the **gtk-common-themes**, the **gnome-system-monitor**.

Why are there multiple entries of some of the applications (and each one of takes a good 3-5 seconds, and even more)?

How can I disable and/or remove some of these loopx devices when I don't use the associated application/services very often? This would definitely speed up my boot process!

Any help and guidance are really appreciated.

Abbas.

Comment: If you are asking about boot speed, please edit your question to include the complete output of `systemd-analyze critical-chain`

Comment: boot time cut in half by removing snap
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2391341 & https://askubuntu.com/questions/1039411/how-can-i-replace-snap-application-such-as-gnome-calculator-with-a-deb & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/948861/why-would-i-want-to-install-a-snap-if-i-can-install-via-apt-instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the output from my history file, thats why the numbers are shown. It includes the errors I may have made. Your `snap list` looks a lot longer than mine was, but you follow same process for all of them.

```
  34  snap list
   35  sudo snap remove gnome-logs
   36  sudo snap remove gnome-calulator
   37  sudo snap remove gnome-calculator
   38  sudo snap remove gnome-characters
   39  sudo snap remove gnome-system-monitor
   40  sudo snap remove core
   41  snap list
   42  sudo snap remove gnome-3-26-1604
   43  sudo snap remove core
   44  snap list
   45  df
   46  
   47  snap list
   48  sudo snap remove core
   49  sudo umount /snap/core/4407
   50  sudo umount /snap/core/4571
   51  sudo umount /snap/core/4327
   52  sudo umount /snap/core/4571
   53  snap list
   54  df
   55  sudo umount /snap/core/4571
   56  ls -l /snap/core
   57  sudo systemctl stop snapd
   58  sudo umount /snap/core/4571
   59  sudo snap remove core
sudo apt remove --purge snapd
sudo apt purge gnome-software-plugin-snap
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I read several online resources, despite having many plus-points, the biggest drawback of the snap is it directly affects your boot! The more snaps you have installed, the slower you boot get! And it gets worse at every step!

Comment: It seems completely removing all the snaps installed, and the snapd service itself is the only solution available right now!