# Why is Ubuntu moving to snaps?

Tags: snap

Why is Ubuntu so set on moving to Snaps. In my view they are a less sophisticated option than Apt packages.

- They **take up more space** on your hard-drive. Which in my case is 200Gb SSD.
- They really bite on **Metered Data Connections** (which is still a reality in much of the civilized world outside of Silicon valley).

Here's an example. If I download 6 Snaps I may be raking in as much as 6Gb of data download and about the same in storage. I run a 50Gb Internet package. Not because I'm to cheap to go uncapped mind you. But because that's all that's available.

Do the same thing with Apt I may download as much as 500mb and store maybe 1GB of data in the end.

So it's fair to say that I'd use my entire data allowance if I upgrade to Ubuntu20.04 and install all applications as Snaps.

That's a huge penalty to pay for developer convenience?

Comment: You may find this post useful: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1035915/how-to-remove-snap-store-from-ubuntu

Comment: you are asking for opinions. regardless:1: with 4Tb disks not an issue 2: with unlimited access not an issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why would I want to install a snap if I can install via apt instead?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/948861/why-would-i-want-to-install-a-snap-if-i-can-install-via-apt-instead)

Comment: "*Ubuntu is set on moving to snaps*" is a classic falsehood. (That means it's simply not true). Some Open Source developers have indeed decided to shift from deb to snap. However, volunteers like you can step in and continue deb packaging. You are not an Ubuntu *customer*. You are an Ubuntu Project *participant*, and the easy answer is *more participation*.

Comment: I think it's a sorta-fair question. On 20.04, snap is installed by default. On top of that, at least one program (Chromium) will install the snap version - even though the user was using apt to install it. It does inform the user - but only after the fact. Even though they installed via apt, it installs the snap, and only informs the user when it's doing the installation. as it's an empty package that installs the snap version. This could be phrased differently, but I think the question is fair. (It may do so for other packages that I don't know about.)

Comment: @KGIII All packages based on React Native & Chromium under the hood i.e. Whatsdesk and several others that use are packaged in the same way. Each of those now run their own Chromium install. Others are simply not packaged for apt. LXD is also now packaged as a Snap. And this is the recommend install. What I mean by replace is that Ubuntu has effectively also displaced the Apt store with a Snap store. This means the average user will load snaps by default.

Comment: and snaps are SLOW

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**2020 Answer**:

In your metered-data situation, it seems unwise of you to use Snaps.

Using Snaps is a *choice* that you have. Nobody is making you install snaps. In your situation, snaps are very easy to disable (`sudo apt remove snapd`).

"*Ubuntu is set on moving to snaps*" is a classic falsehood. (That means it's simply not true).

- Deb packages have been packaged *by Debian volunteers* for over 20 years. Nothing has changed in the Debian world: Volunteers like you can continue packaging any license-compatible open-source software into debs.
- Some Open Source developers have indeed decided to shift their effort from deb to snap. That represents a lack of volunteer interest at those upstream projects, not a nefarious plan or agenda. *Volunteers like you can continue packaging the software into debs.*

**2022 EDIT**:

While technically still true, two years later the 2020 answer has become misleading.

Several desktop components are now installed as snaps (more on the way), and those debs are no longer available in the Ubuntu repositories. Replacing snaps with debs today requires users to go outside Ubuntu to PPAs or upstreams, do some hunting, and take some risks.

This is still not nefarious, and still represents a lack of volunteers required for a healthy deb-packaging community.

Comment: Thanks that answers my question in one go. I'm not trying to stir a debate. Snaps are simply not very practical in my use case. And I'm pleased to hear apt is not going anywhere.  @karel https://askubuntu.com/questions/948861/why-would-i-want-to-install-a-snap-if-i-can-install-via-apt-instead indeed echos the same type of questions I'm asking. Snaps seem only more convenient for developers in terms of dependency management at the cost of more disk, cpu and memory usage for the end user. For some use cases they would probably make sense. Thank you to everyone who pitched in on answering this q.